# Bounding the difference between the PDF of $\hat\beta\sim\mathcal{N}(\beta,\sigma^2)$ and a Dirac delta $\delta_\beta$ in terms of the variance?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function, convergence, dirac-delta

Let $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, let $X$ be a continuous random variable, and let $\hat \beta \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta,\sigma^2)$. Let the pdf of a random variable $A$ be denoted by $p_A$. Consider the random variables $\beta X$ and $\hat \beta X$. As the variance $\sigma^2 \to 0$, it is clear that $\hat \beta X$ approaches $\beta X$. I want to make this precise, if possible.

**Specifically, I am wondering can we get an expression or bound for the difference between the values of the pdfs $p_{\beta X}$ and $p_{\hat \beta X}$ at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ explicitly in terms of the variance $\sigma^2$?**

Here is what I have got so far. Since $\beta X$ is a constant times a random variable, and $\hat \beta X$ is the product of random variables we have
\begin{align}
p_{\beta X}(x) - p_{\hat \beta X}(x) = \frac{1}{|\beta|}p_{X}\bigg(\frac{x}{\beta}\bigg) - \int_{\mathbb{R}} p_{\hat \beta}(t) \frac{1}{|t|}p_{X}\bigg(\frac{x}{t}\bigg) dt.
\end{align}
Writing the first term on the right hand side in terms of a Dirac delta function we have
\begin{align}
p_{\beta X}(x) - p_{\hat \beta X}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta_{\beta}(t)\frac{1}{|t|}p_{X}\bigg(\frac{x}{t}\bigg)dt - \int_{\mathbb{R}} p_{\hat \beta}(t) \frac{1}{|t|}p_{X}\bigg(\frac{x}{t}\bigg) dt \\
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\delta_{\beta}(t) - p_{\hat \beta}(t)) \frac{1}{|t|}p_{X}\bigg(\frac{x}{t}\bigg)dt.
\end{align}

We have essentially reduced the problem to how closely $p_{\hat \beta}(t)$ approximates the Dirac delta $\delta_{\beta}(t)$. And since $\hat \beta \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta,\sigma^2)$, we know that $p_{\hat \beta}$ will converge towards a Dirac delta as $\sigma^2 \to 0$.

Is it possible to go any further and get a more explicit expression, or a bound, on the difference between $p_{\beta X} - p_{\hat \beta X}$? In particular, can we get an expression/bound that involves the variance $\sigma^2$? Or is this the end of the road in terms of what can be obtained here?

It would be great to have something like
\begin{align}
|p_{\beta X}(x) - p_{\hat \beta X}(x)| \le C \sigma, \quad \quad \text{as} \ \sigma^2 \to 0,
\end{align}
where $C$ is some constant. Intuitively something this makes sense as $p_{\hat \beta X}(x)$ will match $p_{\beta X}(x)$ when $\sigma = 0$, but I'm not sure if it is possible to get an expression of this form, or whether the derivations I have given above are as far as we can go?

Comment: Analyzing PDFs often is not productive.  In the present case, even assuming the $\hat\beta$ are independent of $X$ (as you implicitly do), no such result is possible. Construct counterexamples by placing spikes of higher and higher density of $\hat\beta$ at any countable number of locations you like, while shrinking their contributions to the total probability. Although $\hat\beta X$ will indeed approach $X,$ the convergence will *not* occur for the density function at these chosen locations.

Comment: It is very surprising to me that there is so little/no(?) theory on the convergence of pdfs given that these are fundamental objects in probability & statistics. I asked about this here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491740/lots-of-modes-of-convergence-for-random-variables-but-why-is-there-nothing-on-co

Comment: I would assume cases arise where one may be interested in the convergence of a sequence of densities $p_{X_n}$ to a limiting density $p_X$; for this purpose convergence in distribution is not sufficient as it doesn't imply convergence in densities. Very strange that this issue is not considered in the literature as far as I can see.

Comment: @whuber Yes, in my actual problem the $\hat \beta$ depend on $X$ as you appear to have noticed, I left that out to simplify this post a bit. Have you any suggestions on what type of convergence I could look into regarding $p_{\hat \beta X}$ becoming closer to $p_{\beta X}$ as $\sigma^2 \to 0$? I am interested in convergence in both the functional sense and in the pointwise sense (which is the case described in my post). The pointwise sense is probably of even greater interest to me, but functional convergence is also certainly interesting.