# Lots of modes of convergence for random variables but why is there nothing on convergence of probability density functions?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, convergence, measure-theory

There are numerous [modes of convergence for random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables). But why do I never read anything about convergence of probability density functions? It seems like this would also be an important notion of convergence?

On the linked Wikipedia page it states that *"convergence in distribution does not imply that the sequence of corresponding probability density functions will also converge,"* therefore convergence in distribution is not sufficient if one is interested in convergence of probability density functions. So are there any results on convergence of probability density functions?

Comment: The only related result that comes to my mind : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem

Comment: We have [Scheffé's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma).

Comment: @CamilleGontier Givenko-Cantelli is for convergence in distribution which is not enough for convergence of probability densities.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes I saw Scheffe's theorem but that only shows that convergence of the densities implies convergence in distribution. It doesn't provide us with conditions that allow us to show how/when a probability density function (or sequence of probability density functions) converges to another probability density function.

Comment: I really find it surprising that it is so hard to find theory on the convergence of probability density functions when these are some of the most fundamental objects in probability and statistics!

Comment: Part of the issue may be that convergence of a sequence of functions can be ruined by those functions disagreeing on sets of measure 0 - but such disagreements shouldn't generally matter for probability density functions. Such disagreements don't affect the CDFs, so there are more results about convergence of the CDFs, i.e. convergence in distribution.